# Why am I getting "Invalid index" when trying to add a third sheet to my Spreadsheet?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I've got code to add a third sheet:

```
// contextual code
private Excel.Application _xlApp;
private Excel.Workbook _xlBook;
private Excel.Sheets _xlSheets;
private Excel.Worksheet _xlSheet;
private Excel.Worksheet _xlSheetDelPerf;
private Excel.Worksheet _xlSheetListObjectTest;

// the line that kablooeys (sp?):
_xlSheetListObjectTest = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[3]; // <= this is line 307, made infamous in the err msg screenshotted below
```

Adding sheets 1:

```
_xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[1];
```

...and 2:

```
_xlSheetDelPerf = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[2];
```

...work fine, but when I hit the line that kablooifies (Item[3]), I get:

[image]

Why? I took a flyer and changed this:

```
_xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1; // prevent the empty "sheet 2" etc.
```

...to this:

```
_xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3; // prevent the empty "sheet 2" etc.
```

...in case setting "SheetsInNewWorkbook" to 1 was preventing my adding more sheets, but no, it made no difference.

So why is "3" a bad index when "2" is fine?

### UPDATE

For Yacoub Massad, who asked for more context:

```
_xlBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
_xlBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

_xlApp.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;
_xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3; // prevent the empty "sheet 2" etc.
_xlSheets = _xlBook.Worksheets;

_xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[1];
```

If an additional "_xlBook.Worksheets.Add()" is needed for sheet 3, why not for sheet 2?

### UPDATE 2

This gives me "InvalidIndex" on the "Item[0]" line shown below:

```
_xlApp.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = false;
_xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3;

_xlBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
_xlBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
_xlBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
_xlBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

_xlApp.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = false;

_xlSheets = _xlBook.Worksheets;

_xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[0]; // changed to 0 from 1
_xlSheetDelPerf = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[1]; // changed to 1 from 2
_xlSheetListObjectTest = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[2]; // changed to 2 from 3
```

### UPDATE 3

I changed the code in Update 2 to the original indexes of 1, 2, and 3 (replacing the suggested 0, 1, and 2), and I no longer got "InvalidIndex" there; however, I now do further down, in this call to Sort():

```
fruitList.Range.Sort(
    fruitList.ListColumns[1].Range, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
    fruitList.ListColumns[2].Range, Type.Missing, 
        Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
        Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
        Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns);
```

In context:

```
private void WriteListObjectTestSheet()
{
    //_xlBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); // see if this helps
    //_xlSheetListObjectTest = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[2]; // changed to 2 from 3
    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Name = ProduceUsageListObjectSortSheetName;

    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[5, 1] = "Apple";
    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[6, 1] = "Strawberry";
    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[7, 1] = "Cashew";
    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[8, 1] = "Kumquat";
    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[9, 1] = "Pomegranate";
    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[10, 1] = "Banana";
    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[11, 1] = "Pineapple";
    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[12, 1] = "Kiwi";
    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[13, 1] = "Huckleberry";
    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[14, 1] = "Gooseberry";

    Excel.ListObject fruitList =
        _xlSheetListObjectTest.
            ListObjects.Add(Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
                _xlSheetListObjectTest.Range[
                    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[4, 1],
                    _xlSheetListObjectTest.Cells[4, 1]], //13]], 
                Type.Missing, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlNo);

    fruitList.Range.Sort(
        fruitList.ListColumns[1].Range, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
        fruitList.ListColumns[2].Range, Type.Missing, 
            Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
            Type.Missing, Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending,
            Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns);
}
```

I ad[a,o]pted that code from [here](http://I%20adapted%20the%20code%20from%20here%20[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-%20%20us/library/wxks80sb(v=vs.100).aspx]), and admit that I don't really understand it; I reckon the problem is in the ListColumns[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5UIB.png) and/or ListColumns[2](http://I%20adapted%20the%20code%20from%20here%20[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-%20%20us/library/wxks80sb(v=vs.100).aspx]), but don't know why...

Comment: I have no experience with Excel Interop, but how come that accessing an array/list index `_xlSheets.Item[1]` *creates* a new sheet? To me, it seems that the sheet at index 1 was already previously created (or added) and you're just accessing it

Comment: what happen you start the sheets with a `[0]` index instead of `[1]`

Comment: When are you setting `_xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook`? before or after creating the workbook? Can you show the more complete code?

Comment: Adding items 1 and 2 work; it's only when adding 3 that it blows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this line:

```
_xlApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 3;
```

Before this line:

```
_xlBook = _xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
```

As it's name suggests, `SheetsInNewWorkbook` sets the number of sheets for the workbooks that are yet to be created, not the ones that have already been created.

Comment: So you have to both tell it how many to create AND then create them explicitly?

Comment: No. Where are you creating them explicitly? `_xlSheets.Item[3]` does not create a sheet, it simply accesses a sheet.

Comment: The "_xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Items[N];" code is creating them explicitly, isn't it?

Comment: No, its not. This accesses the sheet #N and assigns it to the `_xlSheet` variable.

Comment: What I should have written was this type of code: "_xlBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing);" Does that not create the worksheet, after already specifying how many worksheets you want?

Comment: `_xlBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing)` will add a new sheet. However, if you set `SheetsInNewWorkbook` to say 10 and then create the workbook and then call `_xlBook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing)` then you will get 11 worksheets in total.

Comment: So they are redundant - if I set it to 3, I don't need to call Worksheets.Add() three times, right?

Comment: Yes. As long as you set it before creating the workbook.

Comment: Okay, this has turned into a different issue, so I'm giving Yacoub the green check mark, and will post another.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are trying to access 4th sheet not 3rd sheet when you use following code `(Excel.Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[3]` because its zero based index.

Comment: Then why did 1 and 2 work? Excel interop seems to be 1-based everywhere else (row indexes, column indexes).

Comment: If you create new excel, it by default create three worksheet. i think that is the reason 1 & 2 index is working for you.

Comment: See Update 3; starting from 0 was apparently a mistake.